# Is there sql code to insert into specific range / interval of rows not using ID or Date?

Tags: mysql, insert, intervals

I am trying to write a function to insert into a range of rows without referencing or making use of ID or DATE, say; between row 50 and row 70.
I've tried to use the INTERVAL keyword but it doesn't work as required.
Any ideas, please?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? How are you identifying these rows?  Unless they're ordered by something, an sql table should be considered an unordered set, so rows "50-70" doesn't mean anything..

Comment: @Ian what my function does is to select a number of records based on a specified criteria, split it into different groups; say 16 - 20, 21 - 25 ..., then alter a column between these ranges, setting that column to a specific value for each range split

Comment: Could you show the function - I imagine it's possible to do something with the criteria, but we'd need to see a bit more.  It's also not clear why using an Id woudln't be easier :)

Comment: *what my function does is to select a number of records based on a specified criteria, split it into different groups; say 16 - 20, 21 - 25 ...,* @Ian have said - you need in definite ORDER BY for your numbers to make sense. Moreover, this ORDER BY expression must provide rows uniqueness. Specify this ordering expression explicitly. And I agree - you must provide a sample (CREATE TABLE, dataexample as INSERT INTO, function code...)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.